# [Spring]: Request mapping nested Json with array inside it

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a requestbody as,

```
 {
    "first": "0",
    "second": "3",
    "third": {
        "Types": ["AAA"],
        "Name": "XXXX"
    }
 }
```

i cannot map this to request mapping using spring. I tried with below but it did not work.

public class requestMap {

```
private Integer skip;
private Integer take;
private Map<String, String[]> keywords;

public Integer getSkip() {
    return skip;
}

public void setSkip(Integer skip) {
    this.skip = skip;
}

public Integer getTake() {
    return take;
}

public void setTake(Integer take) {
    this.take = take;
}

public Map<String, String[]> getKeywords() {
    return keywords;
}

public void setKeywords(Keywords keywords) {
    this.keywords = (Map<String, String[]>) keywords;
}
```

}

How can i map the request body?

**EDIT**
Case sensitive key in Json.

Comment: keywords should not be an array, keywords should be an object holding types array.

Answer (score 0):

Change `String[]` to `Object` in your map because `keywords` can have an array or a String instead of only arrays, for example `name` pair has a String value  (and cannot mapped as an array) and `types` has an array value .
So it would be:

```
 private Map<String, Object> keywords;
```

Otherwise, the best option is create an object wich wrappes keyword, annotate with json property, so your properties start with Upper case:

```
 class Keywords {
      @JsonProperty("Types")
      List<String> types;
      @JsonProperty("Name")
      String name;
   }
```

And then used it instead of the map.

---

If you are able to change the json your keywords `pairs-values` could be an array:

```
"keywords": {
    "types": ["P-A01"],
    "name": ["XXXX"]
}
```

Then you'll be able to use the keywords map like your example:

```
 Map<String, String[]> keywords;
```

And of course, you should know that the key `name` will have an array of lenth 1.

Comment: keywords doesn't represent an `array`,, keywords should be an object containing types `array` of `strings`.

Comment: Yes it is what I say, maybe is not well explained

Comment: When i have the keys starting letter as capital, the logic did not work. as "{Types": ["P-A01"],
        "name": "XXXX"
    }

Comment: is it possible you have types and Types, or just Types with uppercase?. I've update my answer. the class keywords with an annotation to resolve it. If instead you use the map, it will be mapped with the key Types and Name.

Answer (score 0):

this should be the correct model.

```
public class jsonObject
{
    private Keywords keywords;

    private String take;

    private String skip;

    public Keywords getKeywords ()
    {
        return keywords;
    }

    public void setKeywords (Keywords keywords)
    {
        this.keywords = keywords;
    }

    public String getTake ()
    {
        return take;
    }

    public void setTake (String take)
    {
        this.take = take;
    }

    public String getSkip ()
    {
        return skip;
    }

    public void setSkip (String skip)
    {
        this.skip = skip;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ClassPojo [keywords = "+keywords+", take = "+take+", skip = "+skip+"]";
    }
}

//keywords class

public class Keywords
{
    private String name;

    private String[] types;

    public String getName ()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName (String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String[] getTypes ()
    {
        return types;
    }

    public void setTypes (String[] types)
    {
        this.types = types;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ClassPojo [name = "+name+", types = "+types+"]";
    }
}
```